# plotting a frequency histogram

Tags: c++

i have written a code in C++ that first sorts an array of decimal values, then asks the user for how many divisions they want for the histogram(to be plotted later), using that to calculate class width, and hence calculating the frequency of values within each class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<float> lengths = {
    2.1, 2.5, 1.8, 2.2, 2.9, 2.0, 1.5, 2.8, 2.3, 2.6,
    3.1, 2.9, 2.7, 1.8, 2.2, 2.4, 1.9, 2.3, 2.0, 2.5};
vector<int> hist;
int divisions;

int main(void)
{

    sort(lengths.begin(), lengths.end());

    cin >> divisions;
    float class_w = static_cast<float>(lengths[lengths.size() - 1]) / divisions;
    float range_top = class_w;
    int freq = 0;

    for (float x : lengths)
    {
        while (x > range_top) //allows range_top to catch up without x moving on to next value
        {
            hist.push_back(freq);
            freq = 0;
            cout << range_top << " ";
            range_top += class_w;
        }
        if (x <= range_top)
        {
            freq++;
        }
    }
    hist.push_back(freq);

    cout << endl;

    for (int x : hist)
    {
        cout << x << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (float y : lengths)
    {
        cout << y << " ";
    }
}
```

the issue arises when the largest/final value of the array is equal to the range_top value.

here is an example of when I took divisions as 10:
lengths(sorted): 1.5 1.8 1.8 1.9 2 2 2.1 2.2 2.2 2.3 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 2.9 3.1
range_top: 0.31 0.62 0.93 1.24 1.55 1.86 2.17 2.48 2.79 3.1
hist: 0 0 0 0 1 2 4 5 4 3 1

it should be. hist:0 0 0 0 1 2 4 5 4 4

what's the solution?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, the issue is the largest value being equal to (or even possibly a bit larger due to rounding issues) the range_top value. A basic solution is to have there effectively be no upper bound for determining the last histogram value. One way to do this is to keep track of the current division value, and ensure it never becomes larger than the maximum one. I've done this by making the following changes:

1. In the `main` function, add the line `int currDivision = 1;`.
2. Change `while (x > range_top)` to `while (currDivision < division && x > range_top)`.
3. At the bottom of that loop, after the `range_top += class_w;` line, add the line `currDivision++;`.
4. Since the largest value(s) may actually be slightly larger than the last `range_top` value, remove the `if (x <= range_top)` line. This was even redundant with your initial code, but we now don't need or want it to ensure that each `x` value is always counted in the `freq` variable, especially in the last group.

With these changes, here's the output that comes from using a divisions value of 10:

```cpp
0.31 0.62 0.93 1.24 1.55 1.86 2.17 2.48 2.79
0 0 0 0 1 2 4 5 4 4
1.5 1.8 1.8 1.9 2 2 2.1 2.2 2.2 2.3 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 2.9 3.1
```

As you can see, the histogram output is now the correct set of values.

Comment: i am getting 0 0 0 0 1 2 4 5 4 3

Comment: @Anonymous I'm sorry about my oversight. With the VC++ 2017 compiler I was using, it complained about using float values, so I changed everything to double. This then caused the largest array value to be less than or equal to the last range_top value, but this doesn't occur when using floats, which is why it worked for me but not for you. There is one more change I should have made, that I explain in my point #4 in my updated answer. Please make that change and then try running the program again.

Comment: thanks you very much, it works. but i still dont understand why this problem arose in the first place

Comment: @Anonymous You're welcome. The problem arose originally because the floating point values are basically stored in binary, so they can't exactly represent all decimal values. Thus, rounding may be involved in some cases. Depending on what is rounded and by how much, there's a chance that the largest value(s) in the array may be larger than the last range_top value. The chances of this happening is larger for floats than for doubles, due to the lower precision involved. As I explained, the problem didn't occur for me initially due to my using doubles instead of floats. I hope this is clear.

Comment: It seems odd to use size of vector `lengths` to determine the width of a histogram "bucket" (i.e., "class width"). I expected it to be based on the _values_ of vector `lengths`—specifically, the maximum and minimum values—rather than the _number of values_. Am I wrong?

Comment: @tbxfreeware I suggest you ask the OP about this instead as its their code. Nonetheless, note the program only uses the size of vector `lengths` to get its last member value which, after being sorted, has the largest value. It then divides this by `divisions` to get the # of equal sized histogram "bucket" widths going from 0 to the largest value. I agree it'd likely be better to start from the minimum value rather than 0, but that would require some other code changes to handle properly. In my answer, I just focused on what specifically was wrong, and how to fairly simply & easily fix it.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. Thanks for the explanation. You got my up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue arises when the largest/final value of the array is equal to the `range_top` value. [This causes an extra histogram bucket to be added to the histogram, which contains the values that are equal to the `range_top` value.]

You are a victim of the inexact representation of floating-point values.

Your program computes each `range_top` value by summing the prior `range_top` value and `class_w`. By the time you reach the 10th histogram bucket, you have done the sum 9 times. The accumulated round-off error of that calculation has resulted in a value for `range_top` that is a tiny bit less than the `3.1` you are expecting. It is less than the `3.1` from vector `lengths`, which causes a new histogram bucket to be created.

I expect this has something to do with the fact that the base-10 value `0.1` is an infinitely repeating "decimal" when converted to base 2. The base-2 value must be truncated for storage in type `float`, which leads to the round-off error described above.

> What's the solution?

The solution is simple. Fill every histogram bucket, except for the last. Anything left over, goes in the final histogram bucket.

Another thing you can do is to perform floating-point computations with type `double`, rather than type `float`. Type `float` is good for between 6 and 7 decimal digits of precision. Type `double` gives you 15 to 16. Both are subject to round-off error, but type `float` hits you much sooner.

Type `float` may be appropriate—after computation is complete—when you need to store a large vector of results. Very rarely should it be used for the computations themselves.

##### Use a zero-based range for the histogram?

The histogram in your program begins at 0.0, and extends out to the largest value from vector `lengths`. As a consequence, the first few buckets in the histogram are empty, because none of the lengths are "close" to 0.0.

The width of a histogram bucket (i.e.,`class_w`), is found by first sorting the vector `lengths`, and then dividing the largest length (i.e., `lengths[lengths.size() - 1]`) by the number of buckets (i.e., `divisions`).

```cpp
float class_w = static_cast<float>(lengths[lengths.size() - 1]) / divisions;

// You could also use member function `back` to make this computation:
float class_w = lengths.back() / divisions;
```

You may wish to have your histogram start at the smallest value from vector `lengths`. That would alter the computation of `class_w`.

```cpp
float class_w = (lengths.back() - lengths.front()) / divisions;
```

The program below uses a flag, which allows you to select either method:

```cpp
    bool const histogram_is_zero_based{ true };
    auto const class_w
    {
        histogram_is_zero_based
        ? lengths.back() / divisions
        : (lengths.back() - lengths.front()) / divisions
    };
```

##### Fill every histogram bucket, except the last

The number of buckets is given by variable `divisions`. In a loop that omits the final bucket, the total number of iterations is `divisions - 1`. We save that in variable `imax`.

```cpp
enum : std::size_t { one = 1u };
std::size_t const imax{ divisions - one };
for (std::size_t i{}; i < imax; ++i)
{
    // Fill every histogram bucket, except the last.
}
```

That's fine, as far as it goes, but this loop also tracks an iterator into vector `lengths`. If we hit the end of vector `lengths`, we stop looping.

```cpp
auto it{ lengths.cbegin() };  // iterator into vector `lengths`
enum : std::size_t { one = 1u };
std::size_t const imax{ divisions - one };
for (std::size_t i{}; i < imax && it != lengths.cend(); ++i)
{
    // Perfect!
}
```

The rest is straightforward. The inner loop scans vector `lengths`, and stops when it finds a value that does not belong in the current histogram bucket. Inside the loop (where values do belong in the current histogram bucket), it increments the bucket count.

- "Bucket counts" are stored in vector `hist`.
- The "current bucket" is indexed by variable `i`.
- "Belongs in the current histogram bucket" translates to `*it < range_top[i]`.
- "Increment the current bucket count" means `++hist[i];`

```cpp
    std::vector<int> hist(divisions, 0);

    // Fill every histogram bucket, except the last.
    auto it{ lengths.cbegin() };  // iterator into vector `lengths`
    enum : std::size_t { one = 1u };
    std::size_t const imax{ divisions - one };
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < imax && it != lengths.cend(); ++i)
    {
        while (it != lengths.cend() && *it < range_top[i])
        {
            ++hist[i];
            ++it;
        }
    }
```

##### Anything left over goes in the final histogram bucket

There is no need for a loop here. The count for the final histogram bucket can be found by a simple subtraction of iterators. This works because iterator `it` is still active at the completion of the prior block of code.

```cpp
    // Fill the final histogram bucket.
    hist.back() = static_cast<int>(lengths.cend() - it);
```

##### The completed function `main`

Most of this was discussed above. One new thing is vector `range_top`. Its elements are initialized by repeatedly adding `class_w` to the initial `threshold`. When `histogram_is_zero_based`, variable `threshold` starts out at `0.0`. Otherwise, it starts out as `lengths.front()`, i.e., the smallest value in vector `lengths`.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Helper functions (see below)
//  - get_int
//  - put
//  - operator<<

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> lengths = {
        2.1, 2.5, 1.8, 2.2, 2.9, 2.0, 1.5, 2.8, 2.3, 2.6,
        3.1, 2.9, 2.7, 1.8, 2.2, 2.4, 1.9, 2.3, 2.0, 2.5 };
    std::cout << "Raw data: " << lengths << "\n\n";

    auto const divisions
    { 
        static_cast<std::size_t>
        (get_int("Number of histogram divisions? ", 1, 20))
    };

    std::sort(lengths.begin(), lengths.end());
    bool const histogram_is_zero_based{ false };
    auto const class_w
    {
        histogram_is_zero_based
        ? lengths.back() / divisions
        : (lengths.back() - lengths.front()) / divisions
    };

    std::vector<double> range_top;
    range_top.reserve(divisions);
    auto threshold{ histogram_is_zero_based ? 0.0 : lengths.front() };
    for (auto i{ divisions }; i--;)
        range_top.push_back(threshold += class_w);

    std::vector<int> hist(divisions, 0);

    // Fill every histogram bucket, except the last.
    auto it{ lengths.cbegin() };  // iterator into vector `lengths`
    enum : std::size_t { one = 1u };
    std::size_t const imax{ divisions - one };
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < imax && it != lengths.cend(); ++i)
    {
        while (it != lengths.cend() && *it < range_top[i])
        {
            ++hist[i];
            ++it;
        }
    }

    // Fill the final histogram bucket.
    hist.back() = static_cast<int>(lengths.cend() - it);

    std::cout
        << "Histogram range is "
        << (histogram_is_zero_based ? "" : "NOT ")
        << "zero-based."
        << "\nLengths: " << lengths
        << "\nRange top: " << range_top
        << "\nHistogram: " << hist
        << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

##### Output

First, the output when `histogram_is_zero_based`. This matches the expected output from the OP.

```
Raw data: [2.1, 2.5, 1.8, 2.2, 2.9, 2, 1.5, 2.8, 2.3, 2.6, 3.1, 2.9, 2.7, 1.8, 2.2, 2.4, 1.9, 2.3, 2, 2.5]

Number of histogram divisions? 10

Histogram range is zero-based.
Lengths: [1.5, 1.8, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1]
Range top: [0.31, 0.62, 0.93, 1.24, 1.55, 1.86, 2.17, 2.48, 2.79, 3.1]
Histogram: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4]
```

Next, the output when `histogram_is_zero_based` is false.

```
Raw data: [2.1, 2.5, 1.8, 2.2, 2.9, 2, 1.5, 2.8, 2.3, 2.6, 3.1, 2.9, 2.7, 1.8, 2.2, 2.4, 1.9, 2.3, 2, 2.5]

Number of histogram divisions? 10

Histogram range is NOT zero-based.
Lengths: [1.5, 1.8, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1]
Range top: [1.66, 1.82, 1.98, 2.14, 2.3, 2.46, 2.62, 2.78, 2.94, 3.1]
Histogram: [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1]
```

##### Helper function: `get_int`

`get_int` is a handy function that inputs an integer from the keyboard (i.e., from `std::cin`). It traps invalid (non-numeric) entries, and also traps entries that are out of range.

Using function `get_int` makes it easy to input the number of divisions to use in the histogram. The following code, for instance, limits the value to integers between 1 and 20. The result is saved as type `std::size_t`.

```cpp
auto const divisions
{ 
    static_cast<std::size_t>
    (get_int("Number of histogram divisions? ", 1, 20))
};
```

```cpp
int get_int(
    std::string const& prompt, 
    int const min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
    int const max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),
    std::istream& ist = std::cin,
    std::ostream& ost = std::cout)
{
    int n{};
    for (;;)
    {
        ost << prompt;
        if (!(ist >> n))
        {
            // Trap non-numeric entries.
            ost << "Entries must be integers between "
                << min << " and " << max
                << ". Please reenter.\n\n";
            ist.clear();
            ist.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else if (n < min || max < n)
        {
            // Trap values that are out of range.
            ost << "Entries must be integers between "
                << min << " and " << max
                << ". Please reenter.\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise, accept the entry.
            ost.put('\n');
            break;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

##### Helper functions: `put` and `operator<<`

Function `put` displays the values in a vector. It has two arguments:

1. `ost` – A reference to a `std::ostream` object. Typically, `ost` is `std::cout`.
2. `v` – A const reference to a vector holding objects of type `T`.

Because `put` is written as a function template, it can be used to output any of the three vectors used in function `main`.

```cpp
put(std::cout, lengths);    // Display the values in vector `lengths`.
put(std::cout, range_top);  // Display the values in vector `range_top`.
put(std::cout, hist);       // Display the values in vector `hist`.
```

```cpp
template< typename T >
void put(std::ostream& ost, std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    enum : std::size_t { zero, one };
    ost.put('[');
    if (v.size() > zero)
    {
        std::size_t const n_commas{ v.size() - one };
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < n_commas; ++i)
            ost << v[i] << ", ";
        ost << v.back();
    }
    ost.put(']');
}
```

Given function `put`, it is a trivial matter to write a stream operator that invokes it.

```cpp
template< typename T >
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    put(ost, v);
    return ost;
}
```

Now, you can display `lengths`, `range_top`, and `hist` like this:

```cpp
    std::cout
        << "Histogram range is "
        << (histogram_is_zero_based ? "" : "NOT ")
        << "zero-based."
        << "\nLengths: " << lengths
        << "\nRange top: " << range_top
        << "\nHistogram: " << hist
        << "\n\n";
```

##### Side notes

Professional programmers try to avoid using "global" variables. In a large program, it is hard to keep track of where and when a global variable changes it value. This makes it hard to prove program correctness (on all execution paths). Even worse, it makes debugging almost impossible.

So, I have moved all your global variables into function `main`, where they are "local."

Given the large number of textbooks that use it, you may be surprised to learn that professional programmers almost never use `using namespace std;` in production code. Neither should you.

Instead, professionals just type `std::` every time they need to reference a name from the Standard Library. There are a few exceptions to this, mostly centered around something called *argument-dependent lookup*, but there is not enough space to go into them here. (*Hint:* overloads for `std::swap`  frequently use ADL.)

So, I have eliminated `using namespace std;`.

Type `float` is prone to excessive round-off errors. Unless there is an overriding reason to use type `float`—rather than type `double`—you should use type `double`. One place where `float` is appropriate is for storing *large* vectors of floating-point values (after they have been computed using type `double`).

Nevertheless, I have changed `float` to `double`.